# Qt: Is is possible to get the QScriptEngine from QWebFrame?

Tags: javascript, qt, garbage

I need to get access to the javascript QScriptEngine in a QWebFrame.  Is that possible?

Well, at least I think I need access to it.  In response to a javascript call I need to allocate a new object, return it to javascript **and** hand ownership of the object to javascript so that it can be garbage collected.  It looks like QScriptEngine::newQObject would allow me to transfer ownership.  Maybe this isn't the right approach.

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed [void QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject ( const QString & name, QObject * object )](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject) method?

From the help:

> Make object available under name from
>   within the frame's JavaScript context.
>   The object will be inserted as a child
>   of the frame's window object.
>
> Qt properties will be exposed as
>   JavaScript properties and slots as
>   JavaScript methods.

Maybe that will help you.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for another way to do it since the object won't necessarily have a name.  I just tried addToJavaScriptWindowObject (using a random name) but haven't been able to confirm that the object actually gets garbage collected, ie. my destructor never gets hit.  Does the javascript function collectgarbage() actually exist?  I can't tell.  Thanks.